# Path is missing inside Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've written a lambda function for testing, My intension is to do slightly different things based on the path (like /abc).
Following is the code

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

type MyEvent struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(handler)
}

func handler(ctx context.Context, event events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (*string, error) {

    fmt.Println(event.Path, " --- ", event.Body)
    fmt.Printf(
        "Path: %#v PathParams: %#v QSParams: %#v ReqContext: %#v",
        event.Path,
        event.PathParameters,
        event.QueryStringParameters,
        event.RequestContext,
    )

    //if event == nil {
    //  fmt.Println("Empty event")
    //  return nil, fmt.Errorf("received nil event")
    //}

    message := fmt.Sprintf("Hello %v!", "event.Name")
    fmt.Println("Message is:", message)
    return &message, nil
}
```

The function is being invocked using **API Gateway** Registered route `/test`
Full url look like this: `https://someid.execute-api.regionname.amazonaws.com/default/test`

The issue is getting path as empty string, Following is the log

```
Path: "" // <------- path is missing
PathParams: map[string]string(nil) 
QSParams: map[string]string(nil) 
ReqContext: events.APIGatewayProxyRequestContext{
    AccountID:"xxxxxxxxxxx", 
    ResourceID:"", 
    OperationName:"", 
    Stage:"default", 
    DomainName:"xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.xxxxxxx.amazonaws.com", 
    DomainPrefix:"xxxxxxxxxx", 
    RequestID:"xxxxxxxxx", 
    ExtendedRequestID:"", 
    Protocol:"", 
    Identity:events.APIGatewayRequestIdentity{
        CognitoIdentityPoolID:"", 
        AccountID:"", 
        CognitoIdentityID:"", 
        Caller:"", 
        APIKey:"", 
        APIKeyID:"", 
        AccessKey:"", 
        SourceIP:"", 
        CognitoAuthenticationType:"", 
        CognitoAuthenticationProvider:"", 
        UserArn:"", 
        UserAgent:"", 
        User:""
    }, 
    ResourcePath:"", 
    Path:"", 
    Authorizer:map[string]interface {}(nil), 
    HTTPMethod:"", 
    RequestTime:"", 
    RequestTimeEpoch:0, 
    APIID:"xxxxxxx"
}
```

The function is working fine except the mentioned issue.
What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below is the config you need to do this if you're using API gateway. The whole endpoint in this example would look like this when used... `https://<domain>/members/238471`, where `238471` is the path parameter I want to get hold of in my Lambda...

[image]

And then also add it to the method request, request paths...

[image]

In this example the path parameter has been called `membershipNumber`. Finally you need your Lambda integration request config to be:

[image]